# Extracting a List from a List of Lists (Maxima)

Tags: list, matrix, extract, maxima, eigenvalue

I am using maxima, and I believe I have a simple question: How do I put the eigenvalues of a matrix in a list, so that I can compute the largest eigenvalue?

From what I'm reading, if M is a matrix, then eigenvalues(M) is a list containing two lists, the first is contains the eigenvalues of M, the second is a list of numbers representing their respective multiplicities. So I guess what I need to do is define a new list by extracting the first list from eigenvalues(M)...Not sure how to do that, however.

Another related question: some of these eigenvalues will be complex, so when I take the maximum of the list, will maxima ignore the complex numbers in the list and just look at the real-valued eigenvalues, or it will give me an error?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly we input the matrix:

```
M : matrix([1,2],[2,3])$
```

Then we calculate its eigenvalues:

```
eigs : eigenvalues(M);
```

> (%o56)               [[2 - sqrt(5), sqrt(5) + 2], [1, 1]]

Finally, we extract the maximum eigenvalue:

```
lmax(first(eigs));
```

> (%o59)                            sqrt(5) + 2

With regard to the maximum of a list of complex numbers, remember that the concept of maximum only belongs to the realm of real numbers. There is not a maximum of a set of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about it. I'll assign the result of `eigenvalues` to two variables, so one is the first list and the other is the second. Note that I'm using parallel assignment for that, e.g. `[a, b] : [foo, bar];` assigns `foo` to `a` and `bar` to `b`. Then I'll paste the elements in the two lists together, to keep each eigenvalue with its multiplicity. Finally I'll sort the eigenvalues by magnitude. I'll sort by decreasing magnitude, so the first element is the largest eigenvalue and its multiplicity.

```
(%i2) A : matrix ([1/7, 15/14, 15/7], [-13/7, 85/14, 71/7], [9/7, -27/7, -47/7]);
                      [  1     15    15  ]
                      [  -     --    --  ]
                      [  7     14    7   ]
                      [                  ]
                      [   13   85    71  ]
(%o2)                 [ - --   --    --  ]
                      [   7    14    7   ]
                      [                  ]
                      [  9      27    47 ]
                      [  -    - --  - -- ]
                      [  7      7     7  ]
(%i3) [vals, mults] : eigenvalues (A);
                      1
(%o3)               [[-, - 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
                      2
(%i4) vals_mults : map (lambda ([a, b], [a, b]), vals, mults);
                     1
(%o4)              [[-, 1], [- 2, 1], [1, 1]]
                     2
(%i5) sort (vals_mults, lambda ([a, b], abs(a[1]) > abs(b[1])));
                                       1
(%o5)              [[- 2, 1], [1, 1], [-, 1]]
                                       2
(%i6) first (%);
(%o6)                       [- 2, 1]
```